# Files on my desktop seem to set themselves as hidden files (macOS Catalina), greyed out, even though they don't begin with periods

Tags: finder, catalina, filesystem, invisible-files

I have a strange and recurring problem on my recently upgraded Mac running macOS Catalina

First of all, Catalina has a new feature where you can Show/hide the hidden files on your machine using Cmd-Shift-Period. Press it once to show the hidden files press it again to hide them. AFAIK, this specific keystroke feature is new in Catalina (prior to Catalina, I always used the hack to set the finder defaults via the terminal to see my hidden files).

I normally keep my Finder windows showing the hidden files, because I want to see them.

Recently I noticed that all of  my files on the desktop were greyed out-- like hidden. They were just random files I happened to have left on my desktop.

And what's strange is that ***they don't begin with a period (.)***, the way normal hidden files do. They seem to behave as hidden files even though they don't begin with a period.

If I press Cmd-Shift-Period, they disappear from view like all of the other hidden files. But unlike the other hidden files, they aren't supposed to be hidden.

[image]

If I press Cmd-Shift-Period again, they appear along with the other hidden files in my finder windows

[image]

Just to be clear: these files were NOT hidden yesterday, and I didn't do anything that I know of to cause this. And as noted below, it doesn't happen right away when I put new files on the desktop. I noticed it last week too but now it seems to have done it to even more files that I put on the desktop more recently than when I first noticed it (The same behavior-- Finder seems like it took some visible files and turned them into these invisible files without changing the file names or adding pre-pending periods like you'd expect for invisible files.)

1) I'm not sure what is causing this. What could be causing these files to appear in this hidden state and to have been normal files and then somehow get morphed into this hidden state?

2) How can i fix them? I've never seen hidden files like these-- I've only ever seen hidden files that begin with periods (so with this, you can add or remove the period to change its visibility)— if I do "Get Info" on these hidden files I can see the normal Get Info window, which has options for many things like "Hide extension" but no option to set the file to visibile/hidden.

Was this a new feature introduced in Catalina?

When I create new files on the desktop, the new files are not hidden and behave normally:

[image]

Comment: It seems that `chflags` has been used with `-R` flag. @Jason, try this: `cd ~/Desktop`  ... `chflags nohidden <some-hidden-file's-name-with-extension>` ... `killall Finder`

Comment: hmm, it first tells me ```: Operation not permitted``` and if I use `sudo` then it seems to have no effect (I tried `killall Finder` and made sure the Finder re-opened the windows).  In fact, when I use `sudo` it says ```Operation not permitted ``` anyway. When finder relaunches, all my hidden files are hidden again, so I can only re-show them with Command-Shift-Period, but the chflags command seemed to have no effect on the file I specified (which I specified by exact path

Comment: okay, could be different for Catalina. I'm on Mojave. Also, don't abuse sudo. Can you retry the commands after giving full disk access to terminal in system preferences > privacy & security ?

Comment: **** magic! *** once I granted  "Full disk access" under system preferences > privacy & security to Terminal, I was then able to run `chflags nohidden` at my ~/Desktop (also, I noticed I was able to see auto-suggest from bash which I did not see before as well as run `chflags nohidden .` which fixed the entire directory en-masse)

Comment: @ankii -- I'm not sure where the symptom comes from, but `chflags nohidden` is a good fix for this questions so if you want to leave a SE answer below I will accept it…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We resolved it in the comments as following:

- Give full disk access to Terminal in System Preferences > Privacy & Security.
- Run

  ```
  cd ~/Desktop
  chflags -R nohidden ./
  killall Finder
  ```

  The `-R` flag will unhide recursively everything under the `./` (current directory).
- To hide something back, for example:

  ```
  chflags hidden ~/Desktop/project/.git
  ```

  Don't use `-R` here since git only keeps the top level folder, `.git` hidden, rest all inside it is normal.

Comment: :+1:             :+1:            :+1:            :+1:

Comment: @ankil-- I just witnessed the symptom re-occur, after a forced restart (my computer would not restart — it has a lot of what appears to be memory problems with Catalina even though I have 8 GB ram); Directly after a restart of the machine, I watched all of the files on the desktop simply disappear. I don't think this is come from my profile scripts. this is very strange. I am able to fix them again with the commands above but I still do not know where the symptom comes from

Comment: Yikes, I spoke too soon… now they are gone again and now I can't fix them with the command above.

Comment: this is definitely a Catalina bug … never saw anything like this before Catalina

Comment: can someone please explains to me what "nohidden" actually is? I have used Unix file systems for over 25 years and have always known hidden files to begin with a ```.```. These files appear hidden but do not begin with a period. Can someone please explain when this was introduced? Is this feature specific to MacOS? At first I was able to bring them back into visibility with the `chflogs nohidden` but now that no longer works… they just remain as-if they are hidden files.

Comment: @JasonFB `chflags` changes or sets different file flags. you can read more about it in the page that appears after running `man chflags`. (use `q` to quit it, `b`, or  `f` to navigate it ) or here: https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/chflags/ ... Files/folders can be hidden even if they don't start with period. I don't know where this change is occurring at. You need to look into your computer for that. Start with Safe mode. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: Maybe you have desktop symlinked somewhere in an hidden folder for which  `-R` was used to hide it.

Comment: guess what, as of this morning the hidden files are re-appeared. let me poke around something is very weird. this is a relatively brand-new setup— no migration assistant, I moved from Mojave on one Mac to Catalina on another (and i moved manually without the migration assistant due to ~20 years(!) of cruft having built up on my system). SO the weird thing is this seems out of the blue but I do have several things running.

Comment: I don't think this had anything to do with the nohidden flags. I think Catalina is fundamentally flawed on my too-old/too-slow MB Air from Late 2014 (MBA 11"). Basically the operating system is just too sluggish, and normal operations that work on modern laptops take extreme amounts of time-- I believe this is the most defendable explanation for these strange ghost-like bugs I see, this bug described here being one of them. Althought it may be related to the "nohidden" flags, I think the ghosting & reappearing is related to the OS.

Comment: @JasonFB does it happen in Safe mode too ? Also make a backup, and reinstall OS in place to see if it happens. Posting a new question would be better than my guesses here... Just say that my answer doesn't help in long term.

Comment: I don't really have time to boot into safe mode and sit around and wait/watch for the symptom to re-occur. I'm sorry Apple doesn't pay me enough to do that. "Re-install" takes me 4-6 weeks of work and setup so that's not viable option for me at the moment. Good news is that my brand new MacBook Pro arrives next week (hopefully) and based on what I know I believe many of my "sluggish" headaches will go away when I have a computer that can truly run this operating system

Comment: When I get my new computer, I will likely use Migration assistant to pull from this existing laptop (I just did a "clean install" onto this laptop about 2 months ago— hence my 4-6 week estimate, which includes all of the debugging time spent with Catalina itself, which of course won't repeat on a newly installed OS), so the 4-6 week estimate is high but it is not extraordinary as I am power user.

Comment: honestly it could very week be the "nohidden" flags but it just takes the OS like 1-2 hours to catch up to match what's in the file system. I honestly believe that to be what I saw her and I am leaving this SE ticket as it is mostly for documentation for Apple, not really for any other purpose.

Comment: you may want to post a bug report on https://feedbackassistant.apple.com .. this site is not affiliated with Apple.