# chflags nohidden not unhiding hidden files

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, catalina

Problem: because of an unkown reason all my desktop files and folders were hidden. i managed do unhide all folders, but i can't unhide the files

i tried to unhide the files via terminal `chflags nohidden filename` but it doesn't work. i also checked if the hidden flag is placed, but there is no hidden flag on the files (but they aren't visible). here is the output via terminalcommand `ls -lo`:

`-rw-r--r--@ 1 username     13669 19 Aug 11:54 filename.txt`

i also tried an app called InvisibliX (which isn't under development anymore), with no success
and of course i used the searching function, which lead me to this: [How to unhide files on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309450/how-to-unhide-files-on-mac) with no further success

I'm thankful for every hint you may have for me!

Some additional information regarding the OS:
Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: So you did run `chflags nohidden filename.txt` and it didn't work?

Comment: yes, i tried the command. i also checked if `chflags hidden filename.txt`sets a flag (i checked via `ls -lo` but there was no change

Comment: Your title & question body say you used `unhide`, which is not a valid command. Could you clarify which you in fact used. Does `sudo` make any difference? [as the files show only owner has permissions to write] Can you see the files if you set Finder to show invisibles `Cmd/Shift/.` *stop/period*? Do you see any error message?

Comment: Long shot, but you might also try `xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo [directory]`

Comment: @Tetsujin: you were right, i had written de command wrong (but only in the text here, not when i was trying to execute the command in the terminal. i made sure to not execute an invalid command. i have corrected the command in the text above (it's `nohidden`instead of `unhide`. an yes, i can see the files if i toggle the view setting via Cmd/Shift/. No error messages

Comment: @Tetsujin: `sudo` doesn't change the result, i tried this one too

Comment: @Wowfunhappy: your solution results in a warning: `No such xattr: com.apple.FinderInfo`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392901/files-on-my-desktop-seem-to-set-themselves-as-hidden-files-macos-catalina-gre/393062#393062  @schwing Try moving all files from Desktop to an other folder, like `~/Documents/backup` and see if they're hidden or not. If not hidden, move them back and see if they're fine. If not .. well move them back anyway. Also try after booting in safe mode if the files are normal or not

Comment: i already put all the files into one seperat folder. files are ok, i am able to edit the files too, so i think i can exclude the possibility of corrupt files

Answer (score 11):

Once I copied files via terminal from an iPod to a Mac and somehow they appeared hidden, `chflags nohidden <filename>` did not work, neither the same command with different option flags. Finally, I found [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/104409) which worked fine. So:

1. `xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo <filename>`
2. `chflags nohidden <filename>`
3. `killall Finder` (just in case)

I did it using `*` so I did not have to go one by one.
Hope it helps,

Answer (score 3):

I answered the same question and OP reported that the files got unhidden at first but got hidden later on. Looks like a bug to me.

- [Files on my desktop seem to set themselves as hidden files (macOS Catalina), greyed out, even though they don't begin with periods](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392901/files-on-my-desktop-seem-to-set-themselves-as-hidden-files-macos-catalina-gre/393062#393062)

---

It seems you need a recursive flag.

```
chflags -R nohidden ~/Desktop/folder
```

Then kill Finder to restart it.

```
killall Finder
```

Comment: i tried this on the files, but it didn't work. i also checked the flag via `ls -lo` after restarting finder, but there where no changes on the file

Comment: @schwing See updated answer

Comment: that's exactly the same issue on my mac! i tried the solution procedure, but it doesn't work on files, only on folders. is there maybe a workaround, to copy files with the right (nohidden) flag?

Comment: sorry I don't know..

Answer (score 1):

If it does help, I found what I believe would be a bug.
I tried to use recursive mode to unhide files within root and subfolders.
As long as I would use only the path to Root folder (Documents) the terminal console output was; No such file or directory

```
sudo chlfags - R nohidden /Users/user/Documents/
```

When I copied whole path to the file (use Command+shift+[.] to show hidden files first in Finder), hid or unhid a file within Documents folder, I was also able to just remove the file name from the path and then successfully execute Recursive action to hide/unhide all files and folders within Documents. Is this does look and feel like a bug to me.

Workaround:

```
chflags - R nohidden  /Users/user/Documents/filename.txt
```

the file was then visible.

Next step, remove the file name from the path and repeat command, to either hide or unhide.

```
chflags - R nohidden  /Users/user/Documents/
```

No need to kill Finder to confirm, just move between folder up or down to refresh the window.
It worked for me on Big Sur Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't use `chflags hidden` instead, `setfile -a V`.

Comment: based on `/usr/bin/getfileinfo filename|folder` output in the Terminal, `chflags hidden|nohidden` and `setfile` toggle the same v|V attribute-letter flag. Also, hidden|nohidden is more readable and less vulnerable to lower|upper casing a single letter.